# sqlite WinRT threading issue on Win 8.1 - Windows Phone 8 works fine

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a Win 8.1 app and having some trouble with the latest sqlite winrt version. The following code works without any problem on Windows Phone 8 but freezes on Win 8.1.

```
Database testDB = new Database(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, databaseName);
await testDB.OpenAsync();

Debug.WriteLine("Step 1");

String query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";
await testDB.PrepareStatementAsync(query);

Debug.WriteLine("Step 2");

Task<Statement> statementTask = testDB.PrepareStatementAsync(query).AsTask();
statementTask.Wait();  // <-- freezes on Win 8.1

Debug.WriteLine("Step 3");
```

While this code runs without any problem on Windows Phone 8 it freezes on Windows 8.1 while waiting for statementTask.

I know that it seems not make a lot of sense to use .AsTask() and .Wait(). But this just an example and in the real project it makes sense to run the query synchronously.

However I would like to understand what the problem is. Why does this work on WP and not on Win 8.1?

If I wrap the second statement into a task it completes without any problem on Win 8.1 as well:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => {
   Task<Statement> statementTask = testDB.PrepareStatementAsync(query).AsTask();
   statementTask.Wait();
 });
task.Wait();
```

Of course this implementation does not make a lot of sense either. But why does this one work while the other one fails?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you block on an asynchronous task (especially one you didn't write the code for), you run the risk of deadlock. I explain this in full [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and in an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In summary, what's probably happening is that the Win8 version of `PrepareStatementAsync` is implemented using `await` without `ConfigureAwait(false)`; and this means that if it starts on the UI thread, then it has to resume on the UI thread. If you block the UI thread (using `Wait`), then it can't resume on the UI thread and thus you deadlock.

If the WP8 project uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` (or a different form of asynchronous implementation entirely), then it wouldn't deadlock. Also, your example of `Task.Run` works because it's not starting on a UI thread (it's starting on a background thread).

The best solution is to reevaluate this statement:

> in the real project it makes sense to run the query synchronously.

That statement is most likely false. In particular, it is almost definitely false since you're talking about the UI thread of a Win8 project. The best solution is to use the APIs asynchronously, as they were designed to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your point but there is one thing I do not understand: sqlite winrt is distributed as source. The same source is included in the WP8 project and in the Win 8.1 project. Thus in both cases the implementation of PrepareStatementAsync is exactly the same. How can it work in one case and not in the other?

Comment: @AndreiHerford: There are probably differences further down the call stack. Regardless, blocking on an asynchronous operation is incorrect.